# How to re-use function result in same query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE 
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), birthday)), "%Y") >17 AND 
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), birthday)), "%Y") <22
```

Which is supposed to return the number of people between 18 and 21, and it does. The problem is that I don't like how I'm running the same set of functions twice. How do I avoid that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a magical operator in MySQL called `BETWEEN`. Observe:

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users`
  WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(),`birthday`)),"%Y")
      BETWEEN 18 and 21;
```

Note that the values to be used are inclusive, not exclusive.

Also note that you can do it more simply:

```
WHERE DATE_ADD(`birthday`,INTERVAL 18 YEAR)
          BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 3 YEAR)
```

Comment: Boy, do I feel dumb now. However if there were no such operator, is it possible to like store the result in a variable or something and do it the way I've done it but with the variable instead?

Comment: You could select it as a column, give it an alias, and then reference the alias.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but then I can't really remember why I didn't try it. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case you could use the `BETWEEN` operator, but alternatively you could also use a subquery for the more general case.

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM users
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), birthday)), "%Y") BETWEEN 18 and 21;
```

The subquery version:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    DATE_FORMAT(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), birthday)), "%Y") days_from_birthday
  FROM users
) as sub
```